# Python requests 401 unauthorized when trying to use CrowdStrike's Event Stream API

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

[image: Event streams enabled on API client]

I'm trying to import data from CrowdStrike using thier Event-stream API (which I've made sure to enable for the client I use). After authenticating and using the token I get HTTP 401 unauthorized.

```
client = OAuth2Session(client=BackendApplicationClient(CrowdStrike.get('cid')))
client.fetch_token(token_url=CrowdStrike.get('url_token'), client_secret=CrowdStrike.get('secret'))

response = client.get(CrowdStrike['url_stream']) # 200 OK

# Parse response
j = json.loads(response.text)
url_data_feed = j['resources'][0]['dataFeedURL']

response = client.get(url_data_feed + "&offset=0") # 401 Unauthorized
```

The last step results an 401 unauthorized- even though the request had an `'Authorization': 'Bearer '` header.

I've even made sure the same bearer is used:
[image: bearer comparison]
and the token's expired is set to 30 minutes, so it should be vaild.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
resp = requests.get(url_data_feed + "&offset=0",
                            stream=True,
                            headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
                                     'Authorization': f'Token {token}'})
```

This is due to CrowdStrike's authentication requiring the 'Authorization' header to start with 'Token' and not with 'Bearer' (as defaulted by the `oauthlib.oauth2` lib).

Also, make sure to include the `stream=True` as otherwise the program will get stuck.

[image: CrowdStrike's Event Stream API examples]